# Skipping compilation of a method depending on operating system or framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework

In Visual Studio 2008 I have a Class which is shared between two projects in the same solution.

I have added some calls to "ImageConverter" class which is availabe on the Full .Net framework but not available on the Compact Framework.

It is only used in the full framework project and this compiles fine. But when i compile the Compact Framework project it obviously errors because this class isnt available.

Is there a way to get the compiler to skip a Method if its a Compact Framework or WinCE Target project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional compilation or preprocessor directives like

```
#if CE
 ....
#else
 ...
#endif
```

You can define a set of active directives in project properties, for each build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem.

In the project properties under the "Build" tab you have "Conditional compilation  symbols". Add a symbol here eg. WindowsCE

Inside your code you can now use the #if #endif to group parts of code to be skipped.

Example.

```
#if !WindowsCE

    // Some WindowsCE unsupported code here. 

#endif
```

The compiler will now skip this section.